# Guidelines to deploy a production MEAN Stack app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, mongodb, heroku

### Guidelines to deploy a production MEAN Stack app.

I'm beginning with Full Stack development and I'm studying news topics every week. But, it's really common to find something new that should be used in the beginning of the project.

My first glance with this gave me this kind of checklist:

- Node Express API.
- MongoDB running.
- Angular Connecting on API.

Them, I've started to find some online solutions like Heroku, Modulus and MongoLab for Heroku. Later, Grunt, Karma, GitHub, Travis CI and lots of 'understandings' that changed my code.

I don't have a 'checklist' and I think that I will do it using Grunt in the future. So, when I create a new app, my steps are the following:

- TDD: Karma on Backend, Mocha on Frontend.*
- Node Express API with JWT, Mongoose, ENV variables and connecting on DB.
- MongoLab setted up.
- Public code should be uglified and minified. And images should be sprites.*
- Angular App connecting on API.
- Git Push to 'Staging'.
- Travis CI run tests.
- Heroku upload the build if tests pass.

*I don't know, yet, how to do that.

Well, I'm not doing anything commercial yet, but I pretend to launch some solo applications soon. And this really annoys me. I've read about 10 technical books, finished dozens of online courses and followed a lot of tutorials in the past 6 months. All about MEAN related things, but I don't feel confident yet to deploy a full production app on the cloud.

I know that there may be some subjective answers, but that answers will be objective in the end, because I do know that we have a market standard. Someone may disagree with specific tool, but will use similar tool to accomplish the same goal. Someone may not use 100%, but will use 90% or so.

So, I want to know what should be done to get things done and running in the market standard?

**Answer to on hold**

As I've said, answers can't be too broad because there is a market standard. Someone may use some technologies to accomplish the same goal as someone who uses another technologies. I'm looking for guidelines that can be specific, I'm not looking for specific platforms. An full answer could include agile methods and software requirements while a simpler answer can include a text editor, a version control and a integration phase. If this is not enough, I'll read the rules again and forget about this question. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: "but I don't feel confident yet" - if you don't start, you'll never feel confident enough. What's the worst that can happen? There will be a bug and you will fix it. That's what programmers do, all day, every day (creating bugs and fixing them :) )

Comment: I'm putting apps on production already. But not releasing it to the market, I want to learn how to do good tests before. But I do agree with your comment. The worst that can happen is nobody access my system or it crashes. :)

Comment: Day to day, it will improve, But you have to define which will be better and easily manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guidelines to deploy a production MEAN Stack app.

- On top of this, I like to use yeoman with angular fullstack generator with a grunt based app
- TDD: Mocha with chai on Backend, Karma with jasmine on Frontend.
- Node Express API with JWT, Mongoose, ENV variables and connecting on DB. With babel if you want ECMAScript 2015. I like promise too, in my case, with bluebird.
- MongoLab setted up. `heroku addons:create mongolab`
- Angular App connecting on API. I choose ui-router, and edit a little bit angular code generated, for ex., change to controllerAs instead of use scope.
- Public code should be concate, uglified and minified. And images should be sprites. This and much more do it by `grunt build` task to make a new dist folder with a prod like app.
- Regarding test, `grunt test` will do the work. Or `grunt test:server` and `grunt test:client` separately.
- generator heroku deploy `yo angular-fullstack:heroku`

BTW, I do like your question, same happends to me, maybe still happens. But I don't aim to answer your question, I just want to share my experience.

Comment: And I do like your answer. Nice contribution, thanks! :)